# Shuffle specific elements of a list in Python but not every element

Tags: python, list, random, shuffle

So let´s say i have the following list

```
F = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
```

Now I want to shuffle the elements in this list, but just the one´s from B till E. A should always stay at the beginning. The rest should be shuffeld.

And later on, I wanna put some lists together to one big, eg:

```
FA = [["A1","B1","B2","B3"]["A2","B2","B3","B4"]...]
```

If this is done, I will choose one of this lists and the elements (except "A") should be shuffled.

Can´t come up with a solution ... :(

Comment: Please explain the second case more clearly

Answer (score 3):

Using [`random.shuffle()` source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/random.py#l256):

```
from random import randrange

def random_shuffle(x, fixed_indexes):
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))): # from random.shuffle() source code
        if i not in fixed_indexes:
           # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
           while True:
               j = randrange(i+1)
               if j not in fixed_indexes:
                  break
           # swap
           x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

Example:

```
>>> F = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
>>> random_shuffle(F, set([0]))
>>> F
['A', 'E', 'C', 'B', 'D']
```

Answer (score 2):

We basically shuffle the indexes instead of shuffling the values:

```
import random
def shuffle_except(lst, keep):
    # keep should be a list of the indexes that we want to keep fixed
    # can also be a range or a sum of range
    # keep = range(0, 2) + range(5, 8)
    keep = set(keep)

    start_indexes = [i for i in xrange(len(lst)) if i not in keep]
    end_indexes = [i for i in xrange(len(lst)) if i not in keep]
    # we shuffle end indexes
    random.shuffle(end_indexes)
    # for each element in start_indexes, we move the corresponding element of lst
    # to its counterpart in end_indexes
    for i in xrange(len(start_indexes)):
        start = start_indexes[i]
        end = end_indexes[i]
        lst[start], lst[end] = lst[end], lst[start]


a = range(20)
print a
print a[1], a[5], a[10], a[15]
shuffle_except(a, {1, 5, 10, 15})
print a
print a[1], a[5], a[10], a[15]
```

prints:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
1 5 10 15
[7, 1, 3, 2, 9, 5, 13, 0, 16, 8, 10, 11, 18, 17, 12, 15, 4, 6, 14, 19]
1 5 10 15
```

As you can see, all the element are now shuffled except the ones we have specified.

Now if you also want to groupe multiple shuffle, here's an example:

```
multi_list = [range(10) for _ in xrange(5)]
keep = {0, 3, 5}

for lst in multi_list:
    shuffle_except(lst, keep)

print multi_list
```

Here's the result:

```
[
[0, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 7, 8, 9], 
[0, 4, 2, 3, 1, 5, 7, 9, 6, 8], 
[0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 8, 6, 7, 9], 
[0, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 9, 4, 6, 8], 
[0, 6, 4, 3, 1, 5, 2, 9, 7, 8]
]
```

Again, you can see the columns 0, 3 and 5 always have the same exact value as in the original list

Comment: what are the guarantees that `sorted(before) == sorted(after)`? The swap `lst[start], lst[end] = lst[end], lst[start]` looks suspicious.

Comment: we are swapping elements within the list, we are not overriding them, there is a 100% guarantee that the ending list contains exactly the same elements. You can try every combination

Comment: Imagine that `keep=set()` (empty set). Do you understand why `random.shuffle()` uses `for i in reversed(range(len(x)))` and swaps `i`-th element only with elements from `x[:i+1]`?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure, my guess is that they want to make sure that element x[i] will never stay in its place, is that right? But even if keep=set(), you can test that sorted(before) is always equal to sorted(after)

Comment: no. `x[:i+1]` list contains `x[i]`

Comment: Ok I did my research and I got the reason behind the x[:i+1]. However, this is not really relevant to my solution. end_indexes is an unbiased random permutation of start_indexes. Even if it's true that when mapping the indexes to the values in lst, we add an extra round of shuffling, this may bias the result a little, but will never delete or duplicate an item in the list.

Comment: For those wondering: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/

Comment: If you are interested in theory, see [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). btw, I've checked your code for all L in `for r in range(10): for L in permutations(range(r)):` `sorted(before) == sorted(after)` holds

Comment: Yep thanks, already on it :)

Comment: +1. I've check the bias of the shuffle and it is not worse than my `random.shuffle()`-based solution (for 300000 shuffling, the frequencies of permutations are equal within 0.3% percent)